# What is the meaning of "this"?

Tags: java, constructor, this

```
class ServerSocket{

   ....

   public ServerSocket(int port) throws IOException {
      this(port, 50, null);
   }

   ....
}
```

I know this keyword is used to represent the active object or current object. In this code what is meaning of "this"?
I got this code from ([here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/net/ServerSocket.java.html))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code snippet, `this(port, 50, null)` denotes an explicit call to a **constructor** in the same class, which has three parameters, for two of which you pass hardcoded arguments (`50` and `null`)

Comment: More in [JLS§8.8.7.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7.1) and [the *Using the this Keyword* Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html).

Answer (score 2):

`this(port, 50, null);` means call the constructor of current class which takes `int, int, Object` (*I guess*) as an arguments.`this` refers to the current `Object`. Here it is used to call constructor from other constructor  *i.e* called `ServerSocket(int port, int num, Object x)` from `ServerSocket(int port)`

Answer (score 2):

`this(port, 50, null)` invoke current class constructor.

> @this keyword
>
> - can be used to refer current class instance variable.
> - this() can be used to invoke current class constructor.
> - this keyword can be used to invoke current class method (implicitly)
> - this can be passed as an argument in the method call.
> - this can be passed as argument in the constructor call.
> - this keyword can also be used to return the current class instance @.

Comment: Your answer is not code, don't mark it up as code. Use the toolbar of formatting aids, **[?]** button giving formatting help, and preview area to aid in formatting correctly.